# method to solve Cubic Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

solve the cubic eq with respect to $w$?

$$8p^3(1-c)w^3-4p^2 w^2-pw-1=0 $$

I try to solve it by take the factor of constant term

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: I edited you question so as to make the $\LaTeX$ work.  I put double $\$$ signs around the equation.  Check out the mathjax tutorial.  Cheers!

Comment: Please, do not add tags that have nothing to do with the question, like "differential equations" - "number theory" etc.

Comment: I will show this method , thanx alot

Comment: sorry i will not repeat this mistake

Answer (score -1):

This is more a comment.

Wolfy says
(feel free to edit this into MathJax):

(c - 1) p!=0, w = (-54 c^2 p^6 + 3 sqrt(3) sqrt(108 c^4 p^12 - 466 c^3 p^12 + 765 c^2 p^12 - 564 c p^12 + 157 p^12) + 117 c p^6 - 67 p^6)^(1/3)/(6 2^(2/3) (c p^3 - p^3)) - (24 c p^4 - 40 p^4)/(48 2^(1/3) (c p^3 - p^3) (-54 c^2 p^6 + 3 sqrt(3) sqrt(108 c^4 p^12 - 466 c^3 p^12 + 765 c^2 p^12 - 564 c p^12 + 157 p^12) + 117 c p^6 - 67 p^6)^(1/3)) - p^2/(6 (c p^3 - p^3))

so it's a mess as expected for a cubic.